# How to link a linux samba shared folder in a JSP

Tags: jsp, hyperlink

Is it possible to provide linux samba shared folder link in JSP. By clicking the link shared folder must open in windows explorer. Only links to the shared folder in jsp is required.

I tried `SmbFile.getPath()`, `SmbFile.getCannonicalPath()`, `SmbFile.getUniPath()`...but no success. It is appending url to local tomcat context. Help is appreciated on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of JSP/SMB but a question of "Can I open folder from web browser", and it seems that yes with JavaScript :

[Opening a file system folder/directory from web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218018/opening-a-file-system-folder-directory-from-web-browser)

You will only have to generate your JSP/SMB code to generate such JavaScript.

Comment: I need to open a shared folder on the network can you please help me how to do it.

Comment: First you have to be aware that according to the post it will only work on FF and IE on Windows.

Comment: need only for IE7 and above